# Why does MsiEnumProdcuts not include MS Office?

Tags: excel, windows-installer

I have a MSI installer that installs an Excel plugin.  I'd like to know if Excel is installed and not install the plugin if its missing.  MsiEnumProducts gives a list of installed products *except* Microsoft Office.  WTF? Is there a better way to do this?

I'd like my MSI installer UI to display or not a checkbox to install Excel component if we have Excel.

Puzzled,
Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel is a feature within one of many Office products.  Just because Office is installed doesn't mean that Excel is installed.  It also doesn't mean the version of Excel that you need is installed.

I would instead check certain registry key/values based on your exact needs.

Comment: Office does not show up in the list of installed products either.  Seems odd that MS does not seem to play be its rules in this case.

Comment: The problem with using specific keys as well, is that when newer versions of office come out, I'll have to keep adding keys.

Comment: Maybe someone ran MSI Zap on that machine.  Apart from say Office XP that was pre-MSI, I've never seen Office installed and not show up in the list. I didn't answer this part of the question as I decided to answer the other part of "is there a better way". The remaining question of "WTF"? was ignored as not being professional or a real question.

Comment: I don't really see that as a problem because you have no idea if you're addin will be compatible with future versions until you've had a chance to validate them.

Comment: Thanks Chistopher, I guess I'll look for specific registry keys for excel versions.